# Shiny Server: leafet doesn't display viridis colors in legend

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, leaflet, viridis

I have a problem plotting the colors of the legend using the viridis palette: the colors are not displayed although the legend labels are.

[image]

I tested the same code under Ubuntu with `Shiny Server v1.4.2.786` with `Node.js v0.10.40` (it doesn't display the viridis colors) and under MacOS (it does correctly).

The details of the Ubuntu R session:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.10

leaflet_1.0.1 shiny_0.13.2  viridis_0.3.4
```

This is the legend that doesn't display the colors

```
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addLegend(
      position = 'bottomright',
      colors = viridis(8), 
      labels = viridis(8), opacity = 1)
```

while this works also on the Ubuntu machine

```
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addLegend(
      position = 'bottomright',
      colors = rgb(t(col2rgb(palette())) / 255), 
      labels = palette(), opacity = 1)
```

[image]

It really seems to be a problem with the color codes of the viridis palette (I tried copying/pasting them in a character vector).

A working example

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(viridis)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addLegend(
      position = 'bottomright',
      colors = viridis(8), 
      labels = viridis(8), opacity = 1)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the alpha channel `#xxxxxxFF` of the `viridis` palette. I had this very same issue when making `viridis` the default palette for the **mapview** package. I've written a little function to solve this. The function is not imported to the namespace, so you can access it only via `mapview:::col2Hex`. It is defined as:

```
function(col, alpha = FALSE) {

  mat <- grDevices::col2rgb(col, alpha = TRUE)
  if (alpha) {
    hx <- grDevices::rgb(mat[1, ]/255, mat[2, ]/255,
                         mat[3, ]/255, mat[4, ]/255)
  } else {
    hx <- grDevices::rgb(mat[1, ]/255, mat[2, ]/255, mat[3, ]/255)
  }
  return(hx)

}
```

and the source can be found [here](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview/blob/master/R/mapviewColors.R).

This way, your code should work.

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addLegend(
    position = 'bottomright',
    colors = mapview:::col2Hex(viridis(8)), 
    labels = mapview:::col2Hex(viridis(8)), opacity = 1)
```

Try setting alpha to `TRUE` and you end up with no colors:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addLegend(
    position = 'bottomright',
    colors = mapview:::col2Hex(viridis(8), alpha = TRUE), 
    labels = mapview:::col2Hex(viridis(8), alpha = TRUE), opacity = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Development version of leaflet now supports viridis palettes. https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/364

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Ubuntu machine 14.04LTS. I was able to get the colors on the legend but it looks like the colors are not listed in the colors() function and there for the legends labels are still hex code.

This part of code should retrieve the color names:

```
colors()[match(rgb(t(col2rgb(leafletColors)), 
                       maxColorValue = 255), c(rgb(t(col2rgb(colors())), maxColorValue = 255)))]
```

the modified app.R code

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    library(viridis)

    r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
    names(r_colors) <- colors()
    leafletColors <- palette(viridis(8))

    ui <- fluidPage(
            leafletOutput("mymap"),
            p(),
            actionButton("recalc", "New points")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

            points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
                    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
            }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

            output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
                    leaflet() %>%
                            addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                                             options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
                            ) %>%
                            addMarkers(data = points()) %>% 
                            addLegend(
                                    position = 'bottomright',
                                    colors = leafletColors, 
                                    labels = palette(), opacity = 1)
            })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Let me know it this is helpful ...